# Ruby execute code when inherited class part initialised

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I know it's probably a long shot, but I thought I'd ask:

Since Ruby does not execute the `initialize` method of a parent class unless you explicitly call `super` in the inheriting class's `initialize` method (or unless you don't overload it in the inheriting class), I was wondering if there's some other way to execute code as part of the parent context (maybe a hook) when instantiating a new instance of an inheriting class...

When implementing `B`'s initialization method, this is currently the behaviour:

```
class A
    def initialize
        puts "Inside A's constructor"
    end
end

class B < A
    def initialize
        puts "Inside B's constructor"
    end
end

A.new
B.new

# Output
# => Inside A's constructor
# => Inside B's constructor
```

I was wondering if the output could somehow be:

```
A.new
# => Inside A's constructor
B.new
# => Inside A's constructor
# => Inside B's constructor
```

Comment: This is not specific to `initialize`. It is common to all methods. If a method always implicitly calls the super methods, then, you will not be able to overwrite a method definition of a subclass. That would be very inconvinient.

Comment: You are asking for code in `A` to force something to happen in `B`, where the language constructs are unfortunately working against you. Depending on context though, you may have options. I presume this is for a purpose, e.g. to simplify sub-classing in a framework? Many frameworks provide alternative ways to generate attributes for instance, such that a constructor in a sub-class is not required, and the base class constructor gets to run without awkward instructions to framework users to "make sure you call super".

Comment: I would like to enforce certain inheritance rules. e.g: I don't want classes to inherit from some other classes directly. I wanted to enforce this logic on instantiation of a new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
    def initialize
        puts "Inside A's constructor"
    end
end

class B < A
    def initialize
        super
        puts "Inside B's constructor"
    end
end

A.new
B.new
```

***Output:***

```
Inside A's constructor
Inside A's constructor
Inside B's constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, simply call `super` in the subclass initialize method

```
class A
  def initialize
    puts "Inside A's constructor"
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    super
    puts "Inside B's constructor"
  end
end

A.new
B.new
```

**Output:**

```
Inside A's constructor
Inside A's constructor
Inside B's constructor
```

Comment: If you look at my original question, I'm well aware to the fact that you can call the constructor from the inheriting class by using `super` but this kinda loses the purpose I'm after...

Comment: @MikeyS. I'm super-curious what purpose you *are* after.  The question doesn't make it at all clear. `super` does exactly what you want...